# How to Authenticate Local Host with Spotify API?

Tags: javascript, python, spotify

I am working with the Spotify Web API and attempting to create a new Spotify Player using Javascript and HTML.

However, the instance fails to initialize.

After some research I found that it is most likely due to the fact that I am running a python server on my local host and using flask to render the html and thus Spotify is denying the request. When I simply run the HTML in Chrome, it works.

Is there some lines of code I can use to authenticate my server in some way If I've created an App on the Spotify Developer Dashboard?

```
var workingToken = 'BQDThKGtGDKvFScIZ_JNRkU2WtdcazwLJpvMtXxw2G50l2OmX9iixB56pcdRArSsQvC1AK8yysyIYxDCQoCVNJuNd3fR_f_zDmDs1oUxFsTP64oKuG-dnMFO6qQlj23m81ZZAQgBQZ-l1NXG42IGf_AIsMUBP41v8MtR5ul8-VF81RM2lq35aN1nCElJtbk6or7kb7An59PaNmmR1wfDVS1wAMwX6unmaTE9CbBLB6wToII2by_msxC5zw4ewe3TlHuECD4cvlmIUtYY3Kh-dZc28nIASQ';
window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = () => {
    const token = workingToken;
    const player = new Spotify.Player({
        name: 'Web Playback SDK Quick Start Player',
        getOAuthToken: cb => { cb(token); }
        });

        // Error handling
        player.addListener('initialization_error', ({ message }) => { console.error(message); });
        player.addListener('authentication_error', ({ message }) => { console.error(message); });
        player.addListener('account_error', ({ message }) => { console.error(message); });
        player.addListener('playback_error', ({ message }) => { console.error(message); });

        // Playback status updates
        player.addListener('player_state_changed', state => { console.log(state); });

        // Ready
        player.addListener('ready', ({ device_id }) => {
            console.log('Ready with Device ID', device_id);
        });

        // Not Ready
        player.addListener('not_ready', ({ device_id }) => {
            console.log('Device ID has gone offline', device_id);
        });

        // Connect to the player!
        player.connect();
};
```

Comment: offtop: shouldn't your "workingToken" be private?

Comment: I am trying to understand your question.  So you are using Flask to to create a website it sounds.  When you access the website in chrome (as it is running in localhost), it will or will not work?

Comment: If I copy the script into a new html file and open it on my computer with chrome, it functions. If I render it with flask and  go to local host then it will give me an initialization error. Sorry about the lack of clarity.